# new URL() -- Node.js vs Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, browser

Documentation claims that the WHATWG URL API should behave the same in Node.js and in a Browser, but here is a counterexample:

```js
console.log(new URL('http://exa mple.com').origin)
```

Run this in the browser (or here on stack overflow) and you get `http://exa%20mple.com`

Run this in Node.js (or here on RunKit) https://runkit.com/embed/cfo21jyrrvxq and you get `TypeError: Invalid URL`

The browser's output is incorrect, that is not a valid URL.  Is there a way to make the browser behave like Node.js?  I would prefer a long-term standards-compliant solution to just installing another package.

Comment: You could just use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()`. So your example would look like `console.log(new URL(encodeURIComponent("http://exa mple.com")).origin);`

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan the example you gave throws an error on any string input

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood. What specifically are you trying to do? Use the `URL` constructor for validation maybe?

Comment: You mention _"Is there a way to make the browser behave like Node.js?"_ but what specific feature of the `URL` API are you utilizing?

Comment: Sorry, good points, I didn't really say which features I needed -- validation, hostname, and protocol (origin was more for the easy example).  I guess the legacy implementation does a lot of that, but actually if you do `url.parse("http://exa mple.com")` you get `http://exa/%20mple.com`

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with Chrome's non-standard implementation of the URL interface.
You could attempt to use [Node's URL implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) in the browser.

Comment: I considered that, but it's actually not the same, and uses `url.parse()` instead of `new URL()`. I guess it's the "Legacy URL API" https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#legacy-url-api

Comment: @howrad does the legacy implementation not allow you to use `url.origin`?